# Calling client methods with a name set at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm using signalR to call some javascript methods from the server like so:

```
Clients.Client(connectionId).myJSMethodName(params);
```

Client is of type dynamic so it will call "myJSMethodName(params)" function with that exact name from the javascript.

What i would like to do is to call a function name that is set at runtime. Something like this:

```
string myFunction = "helloWorld";
Clients.Client(connectionId)[myFunction](params);
```

which would translate to

```
Clients.Client(connectionId).helloWorld(params);
```

This is not working and neither is

```
Clients.Client(connectionId).myFunction(params);
```

since this will call the function with the name "myFunction" instead of "helloWorld".

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Clients.Client(connectionId)[myFunction](params);` should work, assuming the call to `Clients.Client(connectionId)` returns an object with the function in it.  What error are you getting?

Comment: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.ConnectionIdProxy'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that i need to call the "Invoke" method like so:

```
string myFunction = "helloWorld";
Clients.Client(connectionId).Invoke(myFunction, params);
```